# Send push notification via Cortana

Tags: c#, push-notification, cortana

I'm writing a program in C# to get the system's public IP and inform the user of the new one if it changes. The problem is I have two ways of informing the user: Email or Cortana. For the first one (Email) I need an anonymous email sender that I don't have, or ask the user to provide his/her credentials (most people won't). Second way (Cortana): Let's say I have the program installed on my home PC and I have Cortana enabled on Windows 10 and a Windows Phone with Cortana. If my home PC's public IP address changed, Cortana will show a notification on my phone including my new IP address.

I saw an API on github  (that can't do this) and Cortana for developers. I thought "actions" can do the job but after reading the descriptions I'm somehow sure that it can't.

How can I do that?

What I did:
I wrote a little program for Windows 10

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/remotecmd/9nblggh4vr31

and the server side app

http://naryhd.com/RemoteCMDServerBETA.zip

This app lets you have your PC's cmd on your windows phone. (locally)

Now I want to add "access from internet" to it, (I did that, but for security reasons I disabled it, now I got a more secure solution for it)

There are 3 things that I do for accessing it from the internet

Command 1:

```sh
netsh http add urlacl url=http://ip:port/ user=everyone
```

Command 2:

```sh
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=\"RemoteCMDserver2\" dir=in protocol=tcp localport=port profile=public | private remoteip=localsubnet action=allow
```

Forwarding that port:

```
var discoverer = new NatDiscoverer();
        var cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource(10000);
        var device = await discoverer.DiscoverDeviceAsync(PortMapper.Upnp, cts);
        await device.CreatePortMapAsync(new Mapping(Protocol.Tcp, port, port, "REMOTECMD"));
```

I used open.nat from nuget to do port forwarding.

I use this code to get the PC's public IP:

```
var discoverer = new NatDiscoverer();
var device = await discoverer.DiscoverDeviceAsync();
var ip = await device.GetExternalIPAsync();
```

I save that IP in a text file, and repeat checking it every minute, and if it changes it will save that IP and send that IP to the user (currently via email) but I would like to send it with Cortana.

Comment: You should rephrase your question to be more specific and include anything that you have done already. Otherwise people will flag this as too broad and that you want us to do the work for you. You should phrase it more like "How do I send notifications to Cortana when X happens?" or something.

Comment: hi there thanks , ok i will edit my question now

Comment: @user3475113 And this time please use proper capitalization and punctuation. Poorly formatted questions are not only hard to read, but will also lead to fewer answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with Cortana, as of right now. You can have a App, on the Phone, that displays a push Notification in the Action Center or on a Live Tile.

Here is some hopefully useful links:

[Toast Notification and Action Center Overview for Windows 10](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/08/toast-notification-and-action-center-overview-for-windows-10/)

[Inside Windows Platform | How to Add Push Notifications to Your App](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Inside-Windows-Platform/Inside-Windows-Platform-How-to-Add-Push-Notifications-to-Your-App)